# How to display image from a google json response using photo_reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-api

I am getting a JSON Response from Google API. But there is a tag in JSON called photo_reference. How to display the image using that tag.

Comment: u still have an issue ?

Comment: nope, i just got my solution. Thank you Omarj for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing alot of research I got the answer which I was searching.

Thought, it would help someone in future.

STEPS :

1. JSON parsing the link, I got a key/value pair dataset in form of
   *NSDictionary* named ***jsonResponse***.

NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

2. Then, I stored the value of key ***result*** in an another
   dictionary named placesResultDictionary, which is in the code given
   below.

NSDictionary *result = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"result"];
    NSArray *photos = [placesResultDictionary valueForKey:@"photos"];

```
            if([photos isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
            {
                for (NSDictionary *dictionary in photos)
                {
                    NSString *photoReference = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"photo_reference"]];
                    NSString *maxWidth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"width"]];

                    NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=%@&photoreference=%@&key=%s",maxWidth,photoReference,GOOGLE_API_KEY]];

                    NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];

                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];

                    [place_photos addObject:image];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_placeHolder.png"];

                [place_photos addObject:image];
            }
```

**Swift**

```
    if (photos is [Any]) {
                for dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any] in photos {
                    let photoReference: String? = "\(dictionary.value(forKey: "photo_reference") as? String)"
                    let maxWidth: String = "\(dictionary.value(forKeyPath: "width"))"
                    let photoURL = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=\(maxWidth)&photoreference=\(photoReference)&key=\(GOOGLE_API_KEY)")
                    let photoData = Data(contentsOf: photoURL)
                    let image = UIImage(data: photoData)
                    place_photos.append(image)
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *photoDict = [[place objectForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *photoRef = [photoDict objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=%@&key=%@&sensor=false&maxwidth=320", photoRef, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
```

Comment: you code has constant width, which was creating problem in my case. Now, my code has dynamic maxWidth as per response received